# install openstack in rhel 7 without subscribe to RHN

Tags: openstack, rhel7

my question is

is it possible to install openstack on rhel7 without subscribing to the Redhat network?

I'm receiving an error of a missing dependency on phython-greenlet and so far the only solution I found is subscribe o the Redhat Network

Thanks

Comment: https://www.rdoproject.org/Quickstart

Comment: I should add that this is a terrible idea, though. And I agree 100% [with EEAA](http://serverfault.com/a/700054/50647).

Comment: I also have to agree, and thanks for the link @aaron-copley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using RH, you need to subscribe to the RHN. Period. If you don't want to subscribe, use CentOS or another RH derivative.

Comment: I was hopping there was an alternative hehehe, thanks EEAA